# Accessing an array with ctypes in Python

Tags: python, c, numpy, ctypes, dllexport

I am writing a ode-solver in C, exported to a Windows DLL and a Python wrapper for the DLL. I am very used to Python, but I'm a complete beginner with C and ctypes too.

A modified solution inspired by the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18679264/how-to-use-malloc-and-free-with-python-ctypes) looks like:

The C-code

```
/* my_clib.c */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

struct data {
  int nr_steps;
  double dt;
  double* t;
  double* x;
  double t0, x0;
 };

double fun_to_integrate(double t, double y){
    return (y - t);
 }

double rk4(double t, double y, double dt){
    double  k1 = dt * fun_to_integrate(t, y),
            k2 = dt * fun_to_integrate(t + dt / 2, y + k1 / 2),
            k3 = dt * fun_to_integrate(t + dt / 2, y + k2 / 2),
            k4 = dt * fun_to_integrate(t + dt, y + k3);
    return y + (k1 + 2 * k2 + 2 * k3 + k4) / 6;
}

__declspec(dllexport) void my_fun(struct data* pointer){
    int i;
    double dt;
    dt = pointer->dt;
    pointer->t[0] = pointer->t0;
    pointer->x[0] = pointer->x0;
    for(i = 1; i < pointer->nr_steps; i++){
        pointer->t[i] = dt*i + pointer->t0;
        pointer->x[i] = rk4(pointer->t[i-1], pointer->x[i-1], dt);
    }
 }
```

With the corresponding Python file

```
# my_python.py
import ctypes
import numpy as np

class DATA(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
                ('nr_steps', ctypes.c_int),
                ('dt', ctypes.c_double),
                ('t', ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double)),
                ('x', ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double)),
                ('t0', ctypes.c_double),
                ('x0', ctypes.c_double)]

    def __init__(self):
        self.nr_steps = 1000
        self.dt = 0.00001
        self.t0 = 0.
        self.x0 = 2./3
        self.t = (ctypes.c_double * self.nr_steps)()
        self.x = (ctypes.c_double * self.nr_steps)()

class SOLVER(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.clib = ctypes.CDLL('rk4.dll')
        self.clib.my_fun.argtypes = [ctypes.POINTER(DATA)]
        self.clib.my_fun.restype = None

    def func(self, data_struc):
        self.clib.my_fun(ctypes.byref(data_struc))

solver = SOLVER()
data = DATA()
solver.func(data)
```

Compiled with `gcc -o -c my_clib.o my_clib.c` + `gcc -o rk4.dll -shared my_clib.o` using MinGW on Windows 8.

Everything runs fine and after the final line `solver.func()` the time data and solution data are stored in `data.t` and `data.x`. Now I need to access the calculated data from the pointers. It seems it cannot be done directly. If you do `type(data.x)` you get `<class '__main__.LP_c_double'>`, but if you try to access `type(data.x[i])` you get a standard `double`.

Every time I tried to for example `plot(data.t, data.x)` or cast it to `np.array(data.t)`, the Python file crashes and the cmd freezes. However i figured that `x_python = [data.x[i] for x i in range(*number_of_elements*)]` works, but it is very slow if the arrays are long.

My question is: what is the correct/best way of accessing the data calculated in the C-solver?

Also, if this is not the best way of passing an array from C to Python, what other alternatives are suitable for this kind of application? I.e. for every time step, or maybe after reaching some final time, passing the solution `(t, x)` (tuple or two arrays) from C to Python?

Comment: You want `data.x` to be a numpy array, so use that. Rename the ctypes structure field to `_x`. Then in `__init__` set `self.x = np.zeros(self.nr_steps);` `self._x = self.x.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double))`. Do the same for the `t` array.

Comment: Thank you! This seems to work perfectly fine. Is the pointer pointing at the memory adress of the np.array or some "new" memory slot, from which the data is copied from (to the np.array) at the end?

Comment: It's pointing at the numpy array's internal buffer. You can see for yourself in the source for the array's `ctypes` descriptor implemented as [`array_ctypes_get`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.9.2/numpy/core/src/multiarray/getset.c#L243). To expand on what `PyArray_DATA(self)` returns, here are the definitions of the [`PyArrayObject`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.9.2/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h#L635) structure and the [`PyArray_DATA`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.9.2/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h#L1459) function.

Comment: The descriptor returns an instance of the [`numpy.core._internal._ctypes`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.9.2/numpy/core/_internal.py#L224) class, for which you see `data_as` simply calls `ctypes.cast`.

Answer (score 0):

To access values from ctypes objects that acts int, long, etc. use:

```
x = ctypes.c_int(123)
print x.value
```

So, you can iterate over them and make your array.

Also, you can pass a clear C static array to Python instead of using structures, and use numpy's ctypes support to get the numpy.ndarray, or use Python's array module.

But, I get your point using the structure. These are easy and clean ways to do it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Dalen. However, I think I stick with eryksuns suggenstion.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`numpy.ctypeslib.as_array`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.ctypeslib.html#numpy.ctypeslib.as_array).

> Create a numpy array from a ctypes array or a ctypes POINTER. The numpy array shares the memory with the ctypes object.

```
numpy.ctypeslib.as_array(data.x, (data.nr_steps,)
```

There is just a little [issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/2671) with reusing the same pointer with a different shape.

Comment: Why would you do this instead of letting numpy own the memory? The OP only wants a `double *` pointer for the structure. So it's simplest to just create a numpy array and store a pointer to it in the structure. Creating a ctypes array is inefficient and pointless.

Comment: @eryksun I probably wouldn't but could. Would you mind to post your comment as an answer. It is good and might be of interest for more people. And also OP seemed to considere it beeing the answer.

Comment: @tynn Thank you for your answer as well. I'm not completely sure about the difference between your answer and eryksun's. Anyway, I agree with you, if eryksun posts his comment as an answer, I'll accept it.