# How to create equivalent struct in python and use malloc to change reference of null pointer

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

I am 'translating' code from C++ to python using ctypes. Normally I wouldn't sit and translate code from C++ to Python, but the project I'm working on calls for it.

The original C++ code has a struct formatted in the following way;

```
typedef struct {
        ViChar resourceString[256];
    }BP2_DEVICE;
```

In the main code, the pointer was initialized as follows;

```
BP2_DEVICE* resStr = 0;
```

And then memory is allocated;

```
resStr = (BP2_DEVICE *)malloc(256);
```

In searching the web for help, I read that creating a class to represent the BP2_Device struct would work;

```
class BP2_Device:
    def __init__(self, resourceString):
        self.resourceString = resourceString
```

Though, I'm not sure how I would incorporate the fact that 'resourceString' needs to be a mutable array. I know that the code to make resourceString into a mutable array would be as follows;

```
resourceString = ct.create_string_buffer(256)
```

As to how to make it work with the struct/class, I don't know.

I've also looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18679264/how-to-use-malloc-and-free-with-python-ctypes) question for help with malloc, but their setup isn't entirely like mine.

The overall code is pretty lengthy and I don't want to overwhelm the question with it. If there's anything I need to add to clarify please let me know. Any and all help is appreciated, thank-you.

Comment: Allocating four bytes for something that obviously is at least 256 bytes in length, is not going to end well.

Comment: It looks like they're trying (and failing) to build a resizable array.  If that's the case, you can just use a regular old list or tuple or string or whatever makes sense.

Comment: If you are translating C++ code to Python, why do you need `ctypes`?  It's generally used for interfacing to C APIs.  If translating to pure Python, all you need is `bytearray(256)`.

Comment: No matter what the structure contents would be, on *64bit*, you'll have ***Undefined Behavior*** (because of `malloc(4)`).

Comment: @SamVarshavchik That was a typo on my part, meant to put 256 instead of 4.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I'm essentially using the C++ program I'm translating as a template on how to use some functions that are defined in a shared library (dll). I need ctypes because I'm accessing the functions from the dll via python and using the existing C++ program as an example/guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you want to use the structure, but if `resourceString` is a null-terminated string, this works:

```
from ctypes import *

class Bp2Device(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('resourceString',c_char * 256)]

dev = Bp2Device(b'some resource string')
print(dev.resourceString)
dev.resourceString = b'x' * 256 #works
dev.resourceString = b'x' * 257 #fails
```

Output:

```
b'some resource string'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\test.py", line 9, in <module>
    dev.resourceString = b'x' * 257
ValueError: bytes too long (257, maximum length 256)
```

Note that `resourceString` is a writable buffer, so you can pass this structure to C DLL functions and they can safely write to it.  `ctypes` handles `c_char * n` arrays specially and will display them as `bytes`, but you can't individually assign values to the elements of the array because of that special handling.  If you want writable elements, use `c_ubyte * 256`, but then you can't initialize the array directly with byte strings.  Example:

```
from ctypes import *

BYTEARRAY256 = c_ubyte*256

class Bp2Device(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('resourceString',BYTEARRAY256)]

b = BYTEARRAY256(*list(b'abcdefg'))
dev = Bp2Device(b)
dev.resourceString[6] = ord('x')
print(bytes(dev.resourceString))
```

Output:

```
b'abcdefx\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```